# ValueError: steps=None is only valid for a generator based on the keras.utils.Sequence class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The decoder module is as follows:

```
x= Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(latent_space)
x= Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
x= Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
x= Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
x= Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x= Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
decoded= Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

I have extracted the latent space representation after training the autoencoder for some work and now wanted to again pass it to the layers of decoders to predict the reconstructed images by below given instruction. But the given instruction is giving this error:

```
test_generator.reset()
decoded_imgs=decoder.predict_generator(latent_space,steps=None) #error in this line
```

---

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in ()
22 #decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
23 #encoded_imgs=reconstructed
---> 24 decoded_imgs=decoder.predict_generator(reconstructed)
25
26

~/VirtualEnvs/deep/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py 
in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
89 warnings.warn('Update your ' + object_name + 90 ' call to the Keras 2 
API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91 return func(*args, **kwargs)
92 wrapper._original_function = func
93 return wrapper

~/VirtualEnvs/deep/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in 
predict_generator(self, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, 
use_multiprocessing, verbose)
1517 workers=workers,
1518 use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
-> 1519 verbose=verbose)

~/VirtualEnvs/deep/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in predict_generator(model, 
 generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, verbose)
401 steps = len(generator)
402 else:
   --> 403 raise ValueError('steps=None is only valid for a generator'
   404 ' based on the keras.utils.Sequence class.'
  405 ' Please specify steps or use the'

  ValueError: steps=None is only valid for a generator based on the 
  keras.utils.Sequence class. Please specify steps or use the 
  keras.utils.Sequence class.
```

Please tell what am I doing wrong in writing this code.
Help required.....

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and fixed it by ensuring that the step size is greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the number of steps to `predict_generator`, so the function knows how many sample steps to get from the generator. Only if you have a generator that implements the Sequence interface, then you can skip this parameter as the sequence includes its length.

Comment: Is this sample steps = training samples?

Comment: what should I mention for steps=?

Comment: @DiptiMishra Steps is usually number of samples divided by batch size.

Comment: I did this but now it is showing this errorTypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-9800009a5638> in <module>()
      2 batch_size=1
      3 
----> 4 decoded_imgs=decoder.predict_generator(testing _samples/batch_size)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not an iterator

Comment: @DiptiMishra You need to give both the generator and the steps, and I think you passed a numpy array instead of just scalars. Steps is a scalar.

Comment: decoded_imgs=decoder.predict_generator(steps=testing _samples/batch_size)

Comment: Please suggest me how to tackle this issue,,,                                       
    TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not an iterator

Comment: @DiptiMishra The error is quite self explaining, you are using predict_generator, but you didn't give a generator as input, you gave instead a numpy array, which won't work.

Comment: I replaced the predict_generator with predict and I only want to predict reconstructed images based on laten space but this time the error is ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (3136,) but got array with shape (1,)............................................expected representation is 3136,1 and even the size of laten space is also 3136,1,but still the error is saying this..I dont know what is wrong with it

Comment: PLS,SUGGEST WHAT COULD BE POSSIBLE ERROR?

Comment: KINDLY HELP ME IN THIS?

Answer (score 0):

Install keras 2.1.3

This version won't produce this error.

Answer (score -1):

When I got this error I had tensorflow with version 1.13.1 and keras with version 2.2.4.

I fixed by downgrading keras with the commands below:

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras==2.1.2
```